# Trouble Setting up tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, http-status-code-404

So, im teaching myself java and im following the setup instructions found in Java for Dummies 3rd edition.  Im trying to setup my computer so that i can run servlets.  ive followed all of the instructions and after i ran the startup file, the tomcat setup seems to be working from this line in my command prompt

> Server Startup in 547 ms
>   however when i type in the following url from the book to test it
>   http://localhost:8080/servlets-examples/index.html

I get this error

> HTTP Status 404 - /servlets-examples/index.html
>
> type Status report
>
> message /servlets-examples/index.html
>
> description The requested resource is not available.
>
> Apache Tomcat/8.0.23

Also i should add, i tried changing the server port in the server.xml file a few times and typing that into the url instead of 8080 and still getting the same message.  ive tried this in chrome and firefox and its not working on either.  has anybody experienced this and know how to fix it? could it be my computers security is getting in the way or the url has changed or did i just not set it up correctly?

Comment: 404 means the server works, but the document `/servlets-examples/index.html` is not found. Did you check if its there where its supposed to be?

Comment: sooo that means tomcat is working fine but the url is invalid?

Comment: Yes. Just check the URL http://localhost:8080 (it should show a default introduction page)

Comment: awesome thank you! could you post that as an answer to i can mark this as resolved

Comment: done, thanks. If you need further help, just ask :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

404 means the server works, but the document `/servlets-examples/index.html` is not found.
Just check the URL http://localhost:8080 (it should show a default introduction page)

Answer (score 0):

Could you post your code/configuration as well? It could be that an xml file is wrong somewhere. Just changing your port, shouldn't matter, unless something else is using that port, which is always worth checking